# Is my proof right? (Prove that triangles produced from bisecting parallelogram are congruent)

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Parallelogram ABCD is bisected by diagonal AD, and produces two triangles ABD and ACD. Prove that triangles ABD and ACD are congruent.

My proof (or at least attempt):

[image]

note I am not a high school student and have yet to learn geometry, I'm attempting to familiar myself with proofs beforehand though. And yes, I know my spelling is atrocious and I should use LaTeX. Thank you!

Comment: Once you have opposite sides equal, the diagonal is equal to itself for he third side of each triangle. Isn't that it?

Comment: I think you got your vertices messed up. In parallelogram ABCD, the vertex opposite A is C, so the diagonal through A is AC. In this case, the triangles ABD and ACD are *not* congruent, and they definitely cannot be the result of bisecting the parallelogram because the side BD in the first triangle and the side AC in the second one intersect.

Comment: @DavidH sorry fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your pick of any of the three choices below:

SSS congruence:

1.) $\overline{AB}\equiv\overline{CD}$ (opposite sides of a parallelogram)

2.) $\overline{AD}\equiv\overline{BC}$ (opposite sides of a parallelogram)

3.) $\overline{AC}\equiv\overline{AC}$ (identity)

SAS congruence:

1.) $\overline{AB}\equiv\overline{CD}$ (opposite sides of a parallelogram)

2.) $\overline{AD}\equiv\overline{BC}$ (opposite sides of a parallelogram)

3.) $\angle{ABC}\equiv\angle{ADC}$ (opposite angles of a parallelogram)

ASA congruence:

1.) $\angle{ABC}\equiv\angle{ADC}$ (opposite angles of a parallelogram)

2.) $\angle{BAC}\equiv\angle{ACD}$ (alternate interior angles)

3.) $\overline{AB}\equiv\overline{CD}$ (opposite sides of a parallelogram)

Comment: I, while taking the long path, essentially did the second. Thanks!